# Why Won't My Angular Template/Controller Load in ngView?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting my routes configured in Angular (1.3.14). I've looked at plenty of examples like [this one](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and [this one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) as well as a few other answers here on SO, and as far as I can tell this is setup correctly, but when I load it in a browser, nothing loads to the screen. There are no console errors, and I've verified that Angular is running by commenting out the $locationProvider line (which adds the hash back to the url).

Code is currently:

### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

app.config([
  '$routeProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateURL: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  console.log("hi");
});
```

### home.html

```
<div>
   HELLO
</div>
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried varying the way I declare the app. I tried adding the ng-app tag to a div in the body, I've tried using the ng-view directive, but neither of these things change the outcome. All the linked resources do load, I can view them all in dev tools. I can also navigate directly to the template file and it loads just fine. I think I'm missing something simple, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`.

Comment: JavaScript is definitely case sensitive, this is the correct cause of the issue.

Comment: Yup, that was it... That's thoroughly embarrassing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This happens to all of us, at least a thousand times.